# Unable to concatenate bash variables

Tags: linux, bash, csv, awk

I collected the data (5000 rows of CSV data), and I want to make a graph of it, but there's a problem. In my haste and excitement, I forgot to note when the data collection started. The `Arduino` program measures temperatures and light levels (more on that in a minute), once per second, and it stamps a relative time-stamp on that observation. The time stamp is the number of milliseconds since the program was launched.
Fortunately I also know what time the program ended, thanks to the Linux timestamp on the file. So working backwards from the end time, I was able to get the beginning time.

Here's the beginning data: (used the head command)

```
10510707,PV1,1,753.00,PV2,2,129.00,TS1,5,114.13,TS2,7,97.70,WWVB,0,213.00
10512621,PV1,1,753.00,PV2,2,130.00,TS1,5,114.57,TS2,7,97.70,WWVB,0,212.00
10514536,PV1,1,752.00,PV2,2,128.00,TS1,5,114.69,TS2,7,97.70,WWVB,0,212.00
10516450,PV1,1,752.00,PV2,2,129.00,TS1,5,114.80,TS2,7,97.70,WWVB,0,211.00
```

and here's the ending data (used the tail command)

```
20067422,PV1,1,700.00,PV2,2,89.00,TS1,5,117.39,TS2,7,96.80,WWVB,0,198.00
20069336,PV1,1,700.00,PV2,2,90.00,TS1,5,116.94,TS2,7,96.80,WWVB,0,198.00
20071248,PV1,1,700.00,PV2,2,90.00,TS1,5,116.94,TS2,7,96.80,WWVB,0,198.00
20073161,PV1,1,700.00,PV2,2,90.00,TS1,5,116.94,TS2,7,96.80,WWVB,0,198.00
```

By my calculation, the timestamp on the first line should be:

```
Mon Aug 21 13:04:42 EDT 2017,10510707,PV1,1,753.00,PV2,2,129.00,TS1,5,114.13,TS2,7,97.70,WWVB,0,213.00
```

and the timestamp on the last line should be:

```
Mon Aug 21 15:44:04 EDT 2017,20073161,PV1,1,700.00,PV2,2,90.00,TS1,5,116.94,TS2,7,96.80,WWVB,0,198.00
```

hear is the script im working on:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do

#step 1. Get the very first millisecond value in a variable
VarFirstMilliSeconds=$ cat newberry_subset.csv | awk -F, '{print $1}'

#Subsequent Milliseconds
VarMilliSeconds=$(echo "$line" |cut -d "," -f 1)

#declaration of 1 second
declare -i x=1000

#August 21 2017 converted into epoch date
VarFirstDate=$(date -j -f "%d-%B-%y" 21-AUG-17 +%s)

# First millisecond time - current milliseconds
VarDifferenceOfMilliSeconds=$(expr "$VarFirstMilliSeconds"-"$VarMilliSeconds")


# Calculated difference of first milliseconds and current milliseconds divide 
by 1000
# to get seconds to add to epoch date
VarDifferenceOfSeconds=$(expr "$VarDifferenceOfMilliSeconds"/"$x")


# epoch date with difference of first date and current milliseconds added
NewEpochDate=$(expr "$VarFirstDate"+"$VarDifferenceOfSeconds")

# converted epoch date to human readable format
ConvertedEpochDate=$(echo "$NewEpochDate" | awk '{ print strftime("%c", $1); 
}')

LineWithOutMili=$(echo "$line" | cut -d "," -f 2-16)

ConvertedEpochTime=$(echo "$ConvertedEpochDate" | cut -d " " -f 4 | cut -d ":" 
-f 1-2)

echo "$ConvertedEpochTime,$LineWithOutMili"


done < "$1"
```

The problem is when I run the script It does not concatenate the variables and it takes an awful long time to generate a csv

Comment: You want to do this all the first columns in the file? or only first and last lines?

Comment: All of the first columns in the file. Also I am open to using awk

Comment: What are those first column values? `20067422` is not an EPOCH time. Why are you hardcoding `21-AUG-17` in the date command

Comment: This breaks in step 1. You need `$( )` around the whole command, not just a `$` at the start.

Comment: @Inian : fist col value is "he time stamp is the number of milliseconds since the program was launched." (as mentioned in first paragraph) ;-)  Good luck to all!

Comment: Read https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice to learn why it's so slow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this all in a single `Awk` command. Aside fixing a couple of syntax issues in your original `bash` script.

As a first step get the origin time in EPOCH in a shell variable and then use that in `Awk` for subsequent conversions on the first field. I've used the `FreeBSD` version of the `date` command seeing you've used the same.

```
origin=$(date -j -f "%a %b %d %T %Z %Y" "Mon Aug 21 13:04:42 EDT 2017" +%s)
```

Now we'll use the `origin` variable and do the required computation as

```
awk -v start="$origin" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{delta=sprintf("%.0f", (start - ($1/1000))); $1=strftime("%a %b %e %H:%M:%S %Z %Y",delta)}1' csv_file
```

or if you want to include the timestamp as a new column and have all the previous columns also do

```
awk -v start="$origin" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{delta=sprintf("%.0f", (start - ($1/1000))); print strftime("%a %b %e %H:%M:%S %Z %Y",delta),$0}' csv_file
```

Comment: You should mention that's gawk-only for `strftime()` and since you're using gawk you don't need an external `date` call, just use `BEGIN{...;start=mktime("2017 08 21 13 04 42")}`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, quick question is there a way I can remove the 1st column of the original csv file before the PV1, within the single awk script (for a cleaner script)